# Parsing network protocols using meta-programming in Go

Tags: go, metaprogramming, binary-data

In JavaScript (Node), I've written a module which accepts a list of fields and their types and returns an object with `pack` and `unpack` methods. Below is the code to pack and unpack IPv4:

```
var ipv4 = proto.add('struct', {
  name: 'IPV4',
  fields: {
    version:       'int:4',
    ihl:           'int:4',
    dscp:          'int:6',
    ecn:           'int:2',
    length:        'int:16',
    id:            'int:16',
    flags:         'int:3',
    offset:        'int:13',
    ttl:           'int:8',
    protocol:      'int:8',
    checksum:      'int:16',
    src:           'IPV4_ADDR',
    dst:           'IPV4_ADDR',
    // TODO: IPv4 OPTIONS
    options:       'raw'
  },
  $length: 'length'
});
//then I can do
ipv4.pack({ version: 4, ... }); //=> buffer
//and
ipv4.unpack(buffer); //=> { ... }
```

Since JavaScript is dynamic, I can meta-program (reasonably) optimised `pack` and `unpack` functions. From what I understand, you cannot dynamically create functions in Go, though it appears this would be possible using the `reflect` package. Is this worth pursuing? Or would it be too costly to use `reflect`?

I'm hoping to avoid writing [code like this](https://github.com/jonstout/ogo/blob/master/protocol/ipv4/ip.go#L13-L152) for every network protocol I wish to parse.

Comment: Just as a quick hint/idea: You could create types for each protocol and describe the fields through [Tags](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Tag). You can access the tags through reflection. This could work similar to JSON/XML marshalling/unmarshalling.

Comment: So it is possible to do rudimentary code generation with reflect, but it's a massive pain in the butt. Basically all you can do is select which function you're going to run (but you have to have the functions largely pre-written) and bind variables into local scope (using closures). For many applications this works well enough, but it's always pretty painful. The simplest example I know of is a package I'm working on to randomly generate instances of arbitrary types. It's not published yet, but here's a snippet of the important code: https://gist.github.com/joshlf13/dcfd1eaf8ab4677d2ad8

Comment: If you want an example of how it can be a *lot* uglier, see here: https://github.com/joshlf13/gopack

Comment: Also, not sure if this is the sort of thing you're looking for, but this might help: http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gopacket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If can accept a semi-dynamic solution, you could take inspiration in the numerous JSON alternative packages for Golang that are designed for speed. Their approach is to tag a struct, then run a tool (as part of a make configuration for example) to generate the `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` methods for the desired types. Which is clearly faster than using tags.

Some examples to help you :

- https://github.com/pquerna/ffjson
- https://github.com/benbjohnson/megajson

Comment: Interesting idea, will look into it